# How to remove background locations permissions from react native app

Tags: android, react-native

I created a simple ToDoList app, i have not added any packages or code to access the location. On publishing on playstore, there is an error which says that your app is accessing background location. I have only installed a single package in my project which is ion icons. I also checked the android.manifest, but i cant find nothing related to background location.

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "todolist",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "eas": "^0.1.0",
    "expo": "~46.0.9",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.14.5",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.5",
    "react-native-ionicons": "^4.6.5",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

android manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: If you inspect the final manifest, ideally in the apk, do you have anything like `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
` or maybe just `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_???_LOCATION" />
` see https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#background

Comment: It'll be easy to provide answers if you could share the package.json and androidmanifest.xml with your question

Comment: i have added the android manifest and package.json here